# SQL query to select all rows from all tables where a wildcard column equals a value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How can I use a query such as this `SELECT * FROM * WHERE % = 'name'` to scan through all the tables in my database for `name`?

Answer (score 0):

your select statement is missing a column. 
so maybe like SELECT * FROM * WHERE $col = '%name';

the quick and dirty answer outside php (say bash) is to

- step one find the tables in the db. tables=`mysql -uuser -psecret MYDB -B -e 'show tables'|sed -e '2,$p'`
- step 2; iterate over tables with your select statement replacing FROM * with for loop using $tables var.
- - step 2.5 as you iterate collect your results in a variable as an array or map.
- step 3; examine that map.

this all said unless the $col is common across all tables, this question does not make sense.